# Python - Cosine gradually reveals small-amp oscillations ("wobbles")

Tags: python, trigonometry

I have a problem that is equal parts trig and Python. I am plotting a cosine over time interval [0,t] whose frequency changes (slightly) according to another cosine function. So what I'd expect to see is a repeating pattern of higher-to-lower frequency that repeats over the duration of the window [0,t].

Instead what I'm seeing is that over time a low-freq motif emerges in the cosine plot and repeats over time, each time becoming lower and lower in freq until eventually the cosine doesn't even oscillate properly it just "wobbles", for lack of a better term.

[image: Wobbling cosine]

I don't understand how this is emerging over the course of the window [0,t] because cosine is (obviously) periodic and the function modulating it is as well. So how can "new" behavior emerge?? The behavior should be identical across all periods of the modulatory cosine that tunes the freq of the base cosine, right?

As a note, I'm technically using a modified cosine, instead of cos(wt) I'm using e^(cos(wt)) [called von mises eq or something similar].

Minimum needed Code:

```
cos_plot = []
for wind,pos_theta in zip(window,pos_theta_vec): #window is vec of time increments
   # for ref: DBFT(pos_theta) = (1/(2*np.pi))*np.cos(np.radians(pos_theta - base_pos))
    f = float(baserate+DBFT(pos_theta)) # DBFT() returns a val [-0.15,0.15] periodically depending on val of pos_theta
    cos_plot.append(np.exp(np.cos(f*2*np.pi*wind)))
    plt.plot(cos_plot)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You don't have to upload the image here, you can put it on a service like Imgur and link it.

Comment: You can still use the SO image uploader -- which is preferable, because it keeps the image around as long as this post exists -- you just can't _display_ it. But I or any other user with the privilege can edit it to be displayed for you.

Comment: Right, thanks: http://i.imgur.com/vkqFk6J.png

Comment: Edited. Can you be clearer about which part of the image is the "wobble" you're concerned about?

Comment: What is the actual mathematical equation that you're graphing?

Comment: jwodder: I am graphing the cos_plot vector whose elements are the von mises / cos eq evaluated at each time step @Josh Caswell: The part where the cosine does not rise to its max amp, in the middle. It does those little small-amp oscillations which I called wobbles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of posterity, in case anyone ever needs an answer to this question:

I wanted a cosine whose frequency was a time-varying function freq(t). My mistake was simply evaluating this function at each time t like this: A*cos(2pi*freq(t)*t). Instead you need to integrate freq(t) from 0 to t at each time point: y = cos(2*%pi*integral(f(t)) + 2*%pi*f0*t + phase). The term for this procedure is a frequency sweep or chirp (not identical terms, but similar if you need to google/SO answers).

Thanks to those who responded with help :)

- SB

Answer (score 1):

What you are observing could depend on "[aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)", i.e. the emergence of low-frequency figures because of sampling of an high frequency function with a step that is too big.

[image]

(picture taken from the linked Wikipedia page)

If the issue is NOT aliasing consider that **any function shape** between -1 and 1 can be obtained with `cos(f(x)*x)` by simply choosing `f(x)`.

For, consider any function `-1 <= g(x) <= 1` and set `f(x) = arccos(g(x))/x`.

To look for the problem try plotting your "frequency" and see if anything really strange is present in it. May be you've a bug in `DBFT`.

Comment: I tried sampling with 100x more points and I get the same problem. As far as I can tell, when I try to continuously modulate the cosine's frequency in time it gives rise to weird dynamics, Here is a picture of what I'm seeing: http://i.imgur.com/DuCGAFP.png. The blue cosine is the "base" one whose frequency is being modulated by the slower green one (i.e. blue's freq is highest at green's peak, lowest at its trough).

Comment: That green line doesn't seem like the `f` of your equation. Can you show a plot of `f`? If it's not aliasing may simply be your "frequency" that is acting strangely... see edit.

Comment: You're right, the green curve is a toy cosine I used to see if I could use any fx at all to modulate the base cosine (blue). So now I think my problem is when I try to modulate the frequency of a cosine according to another periodic function (coincidentally, also a cosine) something odd happens and I get the behavior seen in the image I linked to in my above comment. All I am doing code-wise is, for each timestep t, evaluating cosine(f*2*pi* t) where f =  1+(0.15*cosine(0.1*2*pi* t)).